# Importrange from multiple URLs using Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a newbie for coding and GAS. I can solve the issue via google spreadsheet quite well, but I am looking for better and efficient ways to solve the problem via GAS.

This is the script I wrote so far.

```
function myFunction() {
  
  const app= SpreadsheetApp;
  const activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  const temp = activeSheet.getRange("AE4:AE").getValues();
}
```

As you can see it from a picture, there are URLs and each URL contains a value which need to be pulled out. I want to importrange values from cell "C6" from each URL and print it to the left column. Key to this problem is that one value needs to be imported from each URL to the left.

Google SpreadSheet
= IMPORTRANGE("URL", "Sheet1!C6")

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Puts data in the active cell from Sheet1!C6

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const cell = ss.getActiveCell();
  cell.setValue(ss.getRange("Sheet1!C6").getValue())
}
```

Note: this is not a custom function...not meant to be run by placing in cell of spreadsheet.